# jquery implementation for browser compatibility issues

Tags: jquery

I want to set the display value to `block` for all `<td>` with class `.subjectGroupCompare`
and the rest to 'none'. Been trying all day -eek. Seems like should be simple.

```
$("#SFGPage").children("table").eq(1).find("td").each(function() {
   var $td = $(this);
   if ($(".subjectGroupCompare")[0]) { 
       $td.css("display", "block"); 
   } else { 
       $td.css("display", "none");
   }
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set `display: block` on table cells? That will cause all kinds of problems for your layout, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you want to check if the `$td` has class `subjectGroupCompare` and if so then you need this

```
if($td.hasClass('subjectGroupCompare')) {
    $td.css("display", "block"); 
}
else { 
   $td.css("display", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got your `if` statement wrong.

You have to check whether the specific node has that `subjectGroupCompare` class. You can check it with

```
$td.hasClass("subjectGroupCompare")
```

so in final, your code would look like this

```
$("#SFGPage").children("table").eq(1).find("td").each(function() {
   var $td = $(this);
   if ($td.hasClass("subjectGroupCompare")) { 
       $td.css("display", "block"); 
   } else { 
       $td.css("display", "none");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I depend my selector to your code so if you want to display block/none the td you can try this

this will hide all td that has no class .subjectGroupCompare

```
$("#SFGPage").children("table").eq(1).find("td:not(.subjectGroupCompare)").css("display", "none");
```

display all with class .subjectGroupCompare

```
$("#SFGPage").children("table").eq(1).find("td.subjectGroupCompare").css("display", "block");
```

i think you can also used `.hide()` or `.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not let jQuery do more of the work? The code is cleaner & it places the opportunity for optimization with jQuery, where it's more likely to be optimized/ hotspotted, rather than you writing an loop & 'if' condition manually.

Something like this:

```
var table = $("#SFGPage").children("table").eq(1);
var tds = table.find("td");
tds.filter( ".subjectGroupCompare").css( "display", "block");
tds.not(    ".subjectGroupCompare").css( "display", "none");
```

As @ehdv says, there may be issues setting display:block on table cells. You can investigate those issues & adapt the solution yourself.